# Casting int to float in thymeleaf frontend

Tags: java, spring, casting, thymeleaf

I have something like this:

```
<span th:text="*{a / (b + c)}"></span>
```

where a, b and c are integers. I need the result to be a floating point number.

Any ideas?

Actual code:

```
<span th:text="(*{item.candidates } > 0 and *{item.budgetSeats + item.taxSeats} > 0)?*{#numbers.formatDecimal(item.candidates / (item.budgetSeats + item.taxSeats),1,2, 'POINT')}:'N/A'">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple:

Multiply (at least) one of the numbers with a float e.g. `1.0`.

```
<span th:text="*{ (a * 1.0) / (b + c)}"></span>
```