# Percentage calculation in Thymeleaf - resulting in zero

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

We have a java object:

```
class Course{

    long totalStudens;
    long graduatedStudents;
}
```

And in the `Thymeleaf` page we like to show the percentage of `graduatedStudents` out of the `totalStudens`

So we did something like that but we keep on getting `0` in the result, even when the result should not be zero:

```
<div th:with="result=${#numbers.formatDecimal((course.graduatedStudents/course.totalStudens)*100, 1, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}">
      <td th:text="${result}"></td>
 </div>
```

We also tried something simpler:

```
 <td th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(course.graduatedStudents/course.totalStudends, 1, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"></td>
```

Is it something to do with the `long` and `double` issues? And if so, how to solve it? We prefer to do it in the `Thymeleaf` side and not in the `java` side

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350392/casting-int-to-float-in-thymeleaf-frontend) will help.

Comment: @michalk yes it helped! would you like to add it as an answer for the kudos?

Comment: Watch out, you have typos: `totalStudends` and `totalStudens`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are doing `long/long` division the result will be `long`. If you want to receive floating point precision  result you will have to convert one of the factors to `double` for example by multiplying it by `1.0` :

```
<div th:with="result=${#numbers.formatDecimal((1.0 * course.graduatedStudents / course.totalStudens)*100, 1, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}">
    <td th:text="${result}"></td>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert the long values into doubles using doubleValue() method. Like this:

```
<div th:with="result=${#numbers.formatDecimal((course.graduatedStudents.doubleValue()/course.totalStudens.doubleValue())*100, 1, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}">
  <td th:text="${result}"></td>
```